# Setting depending on values of a setting from another group

Tags: magento-1.9, module, shipping-methods, system.xml

I have a field called "active" in "group1" that should only be shown if the value of the field "username" in "group0" has been entered.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <group0 translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>98</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>                 <!-- show in default is on -->
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>                <!-- show in website is on -->
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    <!-- show in store is on -->
                    <fields>
                        <username translate="label">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>103</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </username>
                    </fields>
                </group0>
                <group1 translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>Groupe 1</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>                 <!-- show in default is on -->
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>                <!-- show in website is on -->
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    <!-- show in store is on -->
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>          <!-- select options model -->
                            <sort_order>101</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Carrier Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>103</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <active>1</active>
                            </depends>
                        </title>
                    </fields>
                </group1>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: don't drop your code, what is your question? explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [consulting the appropriate core file](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php#L346) a cross group/fieldset `<depends>` looks like this:

```
<!-- … -->
<hello_message>
    <label>Message</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <depends>
        <enabled>
            <fieldset>notes</fieldset>
            <value>1</value>
        </enabled>
    </depends>
</hello_message>
<!-- … -->
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can pass in a full config path when dealing with the depends node.

```
<depends>
    <config>your/full/path</config>
</depends>
```

This will then allow you to depend on items outside of the current group.

Comment: It doesn't work. At least not if config field with full path is inserted in the database but not defined in settings layout. Magento 1.9.2.4